# Check if logo, sitename, slogan, and secondary links exist

Tags: 7

How do you check if logo/sitename/slogan & secondary links are enabled from within a function? (outside of preprocess_page)

This seems to work for logo:

```
$logo = theme_get_setting('logo');
if (empty($logo)) {
...
}
```

but this doesn't for secondary links:

```
$secondary_links = theme_get_setting('toggle_secondary_links');
if (empty($secondary_link)) {
...
}
```

Comment: Your example sets `$secondary_links` but then checks `empty($secondary_link)`. Assuming that error is not unique to your example, that may be your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$secondary_links = theme_get_setting('toggle_secondary_links');` is working fine.

It doesn't work if secondary menu is disabled form `admin/appearance/settings`

It works when secondary menu is disabled form `admin/appearance/settings/theme-name`

OR

It works when secondary menu is disabled form `admin/structure/menu/settings` source of **Source for the Secondary links** is set to 'No Secondary links'

Comment: So.. is there a reliable method to check if it and sitename/slogan are present or not from outside of the preprocess_page function in all of these circumstances?

Comment: use `variable_get('menu_secondary_links_source')` or `$theme_settings = variable_get('theme_mytheme_settings');
$theme_settings['toggle_secondary_menu'];` see `$theme_settings` for further details.

Comment: Thanks, I neglected to dsm theme_settings, and was using toggle_secondary_links instead of toggle_secondary_menu.

Comment: Another problem I have with this method, is that if the items in the secondary links menu are tied to permissions (such as my account, and login).. then when logged out the menu does not appear, however the value still returns true. I understand why this is happening, but is there any way to check if the menu has links?